# Numerator of Electron Vertex Function in Peskin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

In Peskin Chapter $6.3$ equation $6.38$ the integral numerator exhibit follwing expression:

$$
-ig_{\nu \rho}\bar{u}(p')(-ie\gamma^{\nu})i(\displaystyle{\not}k'+m)\gamma^{\\\mu}i(\displaystyle{\not}k+m)(-ie\gamma^{\rho})
$$

i am able to simplify the expression to:
$$2ie^{2}(\displaystyle{\not}k'\gamma^{\mu}\displaystyle{\not}k+m^2\gamma^{\mu}-m\displaystyle{\not}k'\gamma^{\mu}-m\gamma^{\mu}\displaystyle{\not}k)$$

yet is still inequivalent to the final expression

$$
2ie^{2}[\displaystyle{\not}k'\gamma^{\mu}\displaystyle{\not}k+m^2\gamma^{\mu}-2m(k+k')^{\mu}]
$$

is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Those expressions are the same, to see this you can use the anti-commutator of the gamma matrices.

Comment: Would you mind to show the steps explicitly, I couldn't obtain it.